# null value by dialog.path

Tags: aem

I have panel in my dialog, & a afterrender listener on panel. I am not able to get the dialog.path in this listener. Below is my code.

```
function()
{
    var count;
    var select2opts = [];   
    var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
    var dropdown = this.getComponent("dropdown1");
    console.log(dialog.path);
    console.log(dialog);
    console.log(dropdown);
}
```

I am able to get dialog object in which i can see the property path which i require. But on console dialog.path prints null. Any Idea.

```
 <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tabcontrolpanel
               //props
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <typeconfigs
                          //props
                            <fieldConfigs jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <option
                                  //props
                                <optionval
                                  //prop
                            </fieldConfigs>
                        </typeconfigs>
                        <displayoptions
                            //props
                            <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <one
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    text="Click to refresh tabs list."
                                    value="on"/>
                            </options>

                        </displayoptions>
                        <opentab
                           //props
                            <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <one
                                    //props
                            </options>

                        </opentab>
                    </items>
                </items>
                <listeners
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    afterrender="Here Code Applies that i sent"/>
            </tabcontrolpanel>
        </items>
    </items>
```

Comment: Post the code for entire dialog along with the listeners.

Comment: Made the changes, Here is my dialog.xml starts from panel which is inside dialog.

Comment: I want to get dialog.path from panel's or dialog's event. Pls tell me what should i use

Comment: What is dialog.path? Does dialog have a path property set or are you trying to retrieve the path of the dialog? If the path property is set then it should be available with your code itself.

Comment: Hi below is the object i am getting CQ.Dialog.CQ.Ext.extend.constructor {titleFromConfig: true, okText: "OK", cancelText: "Cancel", configDefaults: Object, initialConfig: Object…}_lastAccess: 1414168122bbarCls: "x-window-bbar"body: CQ.Ext.ElementbodyCls: "x-window-body"bodyStyle: "padding:2px;"boxReady: truebuttons: Array[2]bwrap: CQ.Ext.ElementbwrapCls: "x-window-bwrap" Objectcontainer: CQ.Ext.Element/somepropsform: CQ.Ext.form.Ba**path: "/content/pwc/uk/en/PWC1/jcr:content/par-followlink/tabs**"//sompepropsxtype: "dialog", I removed some content, i want to access path from it.

Comment: I can get the value that i need if i use the selectionchanged event in selection, same by dialog.path, But how can i get the that component node when dialog open.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting null for afterrender can you try the activate event instead. Probably this should fix your problem to get dialog path, because this event gets triggered once the rendering is done and the panel is active.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dialog.responseScope.path
```